# Using angular project in IE/Net webbrowser

Tags: asp.net, angular, internet-explorer

I am using angular 9 in a project and it works in all the browsers except IE and subsequently in .Net Webbrowser (that is where I need it to work).

When I try to open it in IE / .net webbrowser it gives me a SCRIPT1010: identifier was expected (vendor.js) and is stuck in loading.

I have try the following:

- Follow the [angular deployment guide][1]
- "Add" the commented imports of core-js, classlist,web-animations (installing all the dependencies)
- Edit browserlist to remove the not in front of IE
- Change target to es5 in tsconfig
- Use "ng serve --configuration=es5"
- Added `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` to headers.
- Added `"es5BrowserSupport": true` in angular.json
  [1]: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#local-development-in-older-browsers

Current dependency list:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.1.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "9.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^9.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "9.1.9",
    "@angular/core": "^9.1.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.1.4",
    "@angular/material": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.1.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.1.9",
    "@angular/router": "^9.1.4",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "jquery": "1.9.1 - 3",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^6.3.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^1.11.1",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.10.3"
  }
```

Comment: Which IE version do you use ?

Comment: IE version 11.9

Comment: Do you use other Angular packages, like @angular/localize ? https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/37915 could be related

Comment: I am not using that specific package but is possible that a package is creating the problem, is there some kind of list of packages that produce this type of problems?

Comment: If possible then you can show us the list of packages that you are using in your project. It may help to find that problematic package.

Comment: Post added to reflect dependency list.

Comment: Are you using a destructuring assignment in your code? It is not supported in the IE browser and I found that it can cause the similar error. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: I am fairly sure now that ng2-pdf-viewer is not compatible with IE but haven't found confirmation yet.

Comment: you can check whether any polyfill is available to support it in the IE browser. Check whether Babel transpile can help to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to run the Angular 9 project created using Angular CLI then you just need to set **"target": "es5"** in tsconfig.json file.

you need to do a similar process if you are working with the Angular Asp.Net project.

You can see that when I try to run the default Angular Asp.Net project it stuck on loading.

[image]

After adding **"target": "es5"** in tsconfig.json file it starts working for the IE 11 browser.

[image]

Further, you need to add the necessary polyfills and transpile necessary es 6 code to es 5 to make it work in an IE browser.

I suggest trying to create a new project and try to test this suggestion with it. Once it works with the IE browser. You can implement those changes to your original project may help you to simplify the process.